# Error message resizes itself when scrolling down in review

Tags: bug, review-queues, design

This occurs in the review queue.  I had the tab open and took action on a post that was there, and got this friendly message.

[image]

However, I decide to scroll down on that page for whatever reason, and that message...resizes itself.

[image]

Shouldn't it be the case that the error message stays the same size regardless of whether or not I've scrolled?  It isn't like the information below the post isn't accessible either by dismissing the pop-up.